# How to list files in an android directory?

Tags: android

Here's my code so far:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Pictures";

        AssetManager mgr = getAssets();

        try {

            String list[] = mgr.list(path);
            Log.e("FILES", String.valueOf(list.length));

            if (list != null)
                for (int i=0; i<list.length; ++i)
                    {
                        Log.e("FILE:", path +"/"+ list[i]);
                    }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.v("List error:", "can't list" + path);
        }
```

Yet while I do have files in that dir, it returns me list.length = 0... any ideas?

Answer (score 394, accepted):

In order to access the files, the permissions must be given in the manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Try this:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Pictures";
Log.d("Files", "Path: " + path);
File directory = new File(path);
File[] files = directory.listFiles();
Log.d("Files", "Size: "+ files.length);
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
{
    Log.d("Files", "FileName:" + files[i].getName());
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yury, strangely file.length gives a NullPointerException... any ideas?  Spasibo!

Comment: I think that you do not have files in the specified folder. Try to check file[] for null. If it is null then you do not have any results and file.length causes the exception.

Comment: Appears it was just missing a "/" :) Thanks!

Comment: Worked like Charm! My mobile is Moto G4, **Android N**. If anyone are facing `can't play video error`. You need to go to your mobile `settings --> apps --> your app --> permissions --> enable storage.`  Should do this manually if you are facing this error. Make sure that you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` in your manifest.
For the people who are facing `NullPointerException` - you are trying to access the files in the app's internal storage which are private sorry you can't do that.

Comment: is there something like fileList().clear();? , so i can reuse this method

Comment: if file.length gives NullPointerException even after adding permission in manifest file, go to your app settings and allow storage permission manually

Comment: This answer is no longer applicable to recent Android versions. See https://source.android.com/docs/core/storage/scoped

Answer (score 50):

I just discovered that:

`new File("/sdcard/").listFiles()` 
returns null if you do not have:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

set in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: I know this is truth, but... Is this an answer? Or should be a comment?

Comment: In addition, on Android 6.0+ the permission needs to be granted in Settings->Apps->Your app->Permissions.

Comment: It also return null if Directory is empty

Answer (score 17):

Well, the `AssetManager` lists files within the `assets` folder that is inside of your APK file. So what you're trying to list in your example above is [apk]/assets/sdcard/Pictures.

If you put some pictures within the `assets` folder inside of your application, and they were in the `Pictures` directory, you would do `mgr.list("/Pictures/")`.

On the other hand, if you have files on the sdcard that are outside of your APK file, in the `Pictures` folder, then you would use `File` as so:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Pictures");
File[] pictures = file.listFiles();
...
for (...)
{
log.e("FILE:", pictures[i].getAbsolutePath());
}
```

And relevant links from the docs:
[File](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html)
[Asset Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html)

Comment: Tried that "File[] pictures = file.listFiles();", but it also gives a NullPointException... hmm...

Comment: Appears it was just missing a "/" :) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for saving my day :)

Comment: @SyedNazarMuhammad Ha. And thank you for saving mine, my friend. Always enjoy a positive remark :D

Answer (score 13):

In addition to all the answers above:

If you are on Android 6.0+ (API Level 23+) you have to explicitly ask for permission to access external storage. Simply having

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in your manifest won't be enough. You also have actively request the permission in your activity:

```
//check for permission
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
    //ask for permission
    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
}
```

I recommend reading this:
http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-request

Answer (score 4):

#### Updated working method

My minSdkversion is 21, so I'm using `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()` method to grant permissions **apart** from also adding the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` in manifest. Thus, to get rid of the NullPointerException in spite of having files in your targeted directory, grant permissions as follows:-

#### MainActivity.java

---

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    /*Other variables & constants here*/  
    private final int READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE=100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // ignore the button code

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openWebView();
            }
        });
    

         /*---------------------------- GRANT PERMISSIONS START-------------------------*/
        // Main part to grant permission. Handle other cases of permission denied
       //   yourself.
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

         /*---------------------------- GRANT PERMISSIONS OVER-------------------------*/
   }
```

And the function that list all the files (in MainActivity.java), thanks to [@Yury](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1108213/yury):-

```java
public void getDownloadedFile() {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Download/";
        Log.d("Files", "Path: " + path);
        File directory = new File(path);
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        if(directory.canRead() && files!=null) {
            Log.d("Files", "Size: " + files.length);
            for(File file: files)
                Log.d("FILE",file.getName());
        }
        else
            Log.d("Null?", "it is null");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `path` is not within the assets folder. Either you enumerate files within the assets folder by means of `AssetManager.list()` or you enumerate files on your SD card by means of `File.list()`

Answer (score 2):

Yury's answer needs some elaboration for newer versions of Android.

First, make sure to defined **READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permission in manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Include the below, for SDK greater than or equals to Android 10(Q).

```
<application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"...</application>
```

Now you can list files in a directory.

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Pictures";
Log.d("Files", "Path: " + path);
File directory = new File(path);
File[] files = directory.listFiles();
Log.d("Files", "Size: "+ files.length);
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
{
    Log.d("Files", "FileName:" + files[i].getName());
}
```

Comment: You should probably reference @Yury's original, accepted answer, as you have copied 90% of it and simply added the update for Android 10.

Comment: I'm new to stack overflow as a contributor, I had this problem and thought his answer was not complete so posted this. I'll wait for more views on it if people don't find it helpful I'll remove it, thanx mate for your view appreciate it!

Comment: I think your answer would be OK if you stated that Yuri's answer needs some elaboration for newer versions of Android.

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] listOfFiles = getActivity().getFilesDir().list();
```

or

```
String[] listOfFiles = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory (Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).list();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class GetAllFilesInDirectory {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File dir = new File("dir");

    System.out.println("Getting all files in " + dir.getCanonicalPath() + " including those in subdirectories");
    List<File> files = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(dir, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE);
    for (File file : files) {
        System.out.println("file: " + file.getCanonicalPath());
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that could be happening:

- You are not adding `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to your `AndroidManifest.xml`
- You are targeting Android 23 and you're not asking for that permission to the user. Go down to Android 22 or ask the user for that permission.

Answer (score 0):

Try these

```
 String appDirectoryName = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
    File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
    directory.mkdirs();
    File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
    int a = 1;
    for (int x = 0; x < fList.length; x++) {

        //txt.setText("You Have Capture " + String.valueOf(a) + " Photos");
        a++;
    }
    //get all the files from a directory
    for (File file : fList) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            list.add(new ModelClass(file.getName(), file.getAbsolutePath()));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Android 10/Q and you did all of the correct things to request access permissions to read external storage and it still doesn't work, it's worth reading this answer:

[Android Q (10) ask permission to get access all storage. Scoped storage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60316149/2298819)

I had working code, but me device took it upon itself to update when it was on a network connection (it was usually without a connection.) Once in Android 10, the file access no longer worked. The only easy way to fix it without rewriting the code was to add that extra attribute to the manifest as described. The file access now works as in Android 9 again. YMMV, it probably won't continue to work in future versions.

Answer (score 0):

For the people are still getting `NullPointerException` when they try to get file list, if you using Android `API 29+` then you need to add

```
<application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"...
```

in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Then request for storage permission again.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to list files in android device in a specific folder

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

> IN Kotlin

```
val fileRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
val yourDir = File(fileRoot, "FOLDER_NAME")
    for (f in yourDir.listFiles()!!) {
       if (f.isFile){
           print(f.name)
       }
    }
```

All the file name will be printed with the file extension

Comment: If you use `!!`, you can have NPE. In this case check that `yourDir.listFiles()` is not null.