# How to Read all files from particular external directory into my custom listview in android?

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

i want to display all content of particular folder which is in external directory into my custom List-view or Recycle-view in android

Comment: What you have try ? we are not here to do your home work :)

Comment: i have use recyclerview in my code

Comment: Check out this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646984/how-to-list-files-in-an-android-directory

Answer (score 0):

Below line of code is to retrieve all the files and folder which is in particular path

```
File f = new File(dirPath);
File[] files = f.listFiles();
```