# Android files get repeated

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to list all the files in a directory.
Here is my code:

```
public List<String> MyFiles = new ArrayList<>();
dir = "/storage/sdcard0";
File f = new File(dir);

File[] files = f.listFiles();
for(File name: files) {
    MyFiles.add(name.getName());
}
Collections.sort(MyFiles);
```

The problem is that nearly all the files is repeated.
For Instance I find .nomedia twice and sometimes thrice even thought there is only one file.

Edit:

I changed the code to sort the files correctly thanks to Vishwesh Jainkuniya, but still the same problem the files are repeated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list files in an android directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646984/how-to-list-files-in-an-android-directory)

Answer (score 0):

**Problem-:** sort function is not applicable for `File[]`

**Solution:-** create a string array and sort it.

**Try this-:**

First of all get the path of root dir

`String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();`

Now append your dir name in `path`

`path += "";`

Now get the files in a array

```
File f = new File(path);        
File file[] = f.listFiles();
String[] fileName = new String[file.length];
for (int i=0; i < file.length; i++)
{
    fileName[i] = file[i].getName();
    Log.d("Files", "FileName:" + file[i].getName());
}
```

Now sort

`Arrays.sort(fileName);`

Comment: Oh, yeah sorry.
I edited it but still the same, it's now sorted correctly but still the same problem.
The problem lies in f.listFiles(); I checked the output and it repeats the names.