# java external storage directory library

Tags: java, android, android-external-storage

I want to start by saying that I am very new to java so I am having issues finding resources. I am trying to find a library that will allow for me to access files in a Moto G4 phone. I have found plenty of examples of how to do this but they never say what library they are using. The code I am interested in is the following: (Note that this is an example and not what I will be doing with these files. I just want to get this script to run)

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Pictures";
Log.d("Files", "Path: " + path);
File directory = new File(path);
File[] files = directory.listFiles();
Log.d("Files", "Size: "+ files.length);
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
{
Log.d("Files", "FileName:" + files[i].getName());
}
```

This was pulled from another post [on how to find files on an Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646984/how-to-list-files-in-an-android-directory). Any help would be greatly appreciated. It is important to note that this is just so that I can gain access to these files so that I can move them to my hard drive.

Comment: You dont need libraries to access files. What is it that you want to do?

Comment: What do you mean by access files? Looks like you're trying to just print them? What's `Log.d() ` doing? There's not enough info here.

Comment: You need to use `java.io.File`